# Java Heap Space - Notwithstanding Heap increased

Tags: java, jmeter, heap-memory

The problem i'm facing is that java heap space exception raises up however i have just increased heap space.  I have already increased heap space in

Jmeter.sh

```
JVM_ARGS="-Xms1g -Xmx8g"
HEAP="-Xms1g -Xmx8g"
```

and Jmeter.bat

```
set JVM_ARGS=-Xms1g -Xmx8g
set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx8g
```

inside my testplan there aren't Listner, jmeter is launched by command line but nothing, Java Heap space exception always raises up.

Someone really expert can help me please?

Full exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Dumping heap to java_pid32652.hprof ... Heap dump file created [8922760824 bytes in 40.975 secs] summary + 55 in 00:01:03 = 0.9/s Avg: 9671 Min: 0 Max: 89909 Err: 41 (74.55%) Active: 50 Started: 50 Finished: 0 summary = 3811 in 00:03:38 = 17.5/s Avg: 1149 Min: 0 Max: 89909 Err: 41 (1.08%) Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "boundedElastic-94"
```

Comment: there will be no "silver bullet" for this issue if more heap with `-Xmx...` doesn't help. It depends on your JMeter configuration. There is a small [FAQ entry](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JMeterFAQ#JMeterFAQ-JMeterkeepsgetting%22OutofMemory%22errors.WhatcanIdo?) in the original docs you could try. You also could use the `jconsole` tool to find out, which parts take the most heap to get a clue how to adjust your configuration.

Comment: `java heap space exception raises up ` no it doesn't. That's not a valid Java exception. When some exception is happening you should share the actual exception verbatim. Include the stacktrace.

Comment: I just saw this: in your post you swapped the correct way to set the values for the .sh and the .bat file - in the .bat file it should be `set JVM...` while in the .sh file you don't need the `set` command. Is this just a typo in your post?

Comment: Hi @cyberbrain, yes it's a typo sorry

Comment: The full error is this: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid32652.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [8922760824 bytes in 40.975 secs]
summary +     55 in 00:01:03 =    0.9/s Avg:  9671 Min:     0 Max: 89909 Err:    41 (74.55%) Active: 50 Started: 50 Finished: 0
summary =   3811 in 00:03:38 =   17.5/s Avg:  1149 Min:     0 Max: 89909 Err:    41 (1.08%)

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "boundedElastic-94"

Comment: Then please edit your question, fix the typo and add the stacktrace there.

Comment: Done cyberbrain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm not the "really expert" but I can see that changes in `jmeter.sh` file are incorrect. You should rather use [`export` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Environment.html) for setting environment variables.

[image]

Also you can use the following code in any [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) to get efffective JVM heap size:

```
println('Current heap: ' + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 + ' GB')
```

[image]

More information: [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling)

If your heap changes are applied but you're still facing the error the only way of proceeding will be switching to [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) mode

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, i followed your indication about export command but it doesn't work, even the instruction shows HEAP 8 GB... i don't know :(

Comment: Then 8 GB is not enough, either increase it (you can have [2^64 bytes](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/04/what-is-maximum-heap-size-for-32-bit-64-JVM-Java-memory.html) as maximum) or allocate another machine and go for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: thanks, now it's working.. i needed to increase till 13GB..